Mulesoft, Convert excel data (application/xlsx) into byte [] format
In MuleSoft, How to convert excel(mime: application/xlsx) data into byte[] format
Please suggest the logic, as Binary {class: “byte[]”} it’s not working for xlsx data

Why are you trying to do that? What are you trying to achieve? Please provide details of the use case.

My requirement, convert data into excel format and insert record into db as a byte[]

Have you tried just sent it to the database? What was the result? Share flows, configuration and any errors. I also recommend to read [ask].
